# Having trouble routing to profile homepage, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm having trouble having the root url route to a signed in user's profile page.

This is my config file-

```
 get "profiles/show"

resources :players

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do 
 get 'register', to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :register
 get 'login',    to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
 get 'logout',   to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
end

resources :logistics

resources :notes

root :to => 'notes#index'

get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
```

I want that 'root to' to show the 'profiles#show' view. Just as the get '/:id' route does right below it.

I've tried and researched what I thought would work to no avail. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Follow the instructions here. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Answer (score 0):

Hey try something like

```
match "/:id" => "profiles#show"
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure I'm asking the question correctly. I want when users sign in to be redirected to myapp.com/profilename instead of the root as it currently stands. Can I just move that get ':id', to profiles#show inside of the devise scope?